# Create a multiplication table in Reactjs with map function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

create multiplication in react
I'm going to make a multiplication table in react.
but But I'm confused

Comment: Welcome to SO please read [ask] and take the [tour]. What is the root of your confusion? What did you tried so far to create the table?

Comment: already answered you here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62158014/how-to-create-multiplication-table-in-react-js-with-map-function

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react'


let table=0;

        for(let i=1;i<=10;i++){
            console.log(i)
            table += 5+" X "+i+" = "+(5*i);
        }




function Multytable() {
  return (
    <div>{table}</div>
  )
}

export default Multytable
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).